# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Dag could not be found; either it does not exist or it failed to parse

Tags: airflow-2.x

I recently upgraded the Airflow from 1.10.11 to 2.2.3 after following the steps given in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-from-1-10/index.html. I first up upgraded to 1.10.15 as suggested which worked fine. But after upgrading to 2.2.3, I'm unable to execute the DAGs from UI as the task is going into queued state. When I check the task pod logs, I see this error:

```
[2022-02-22 06:46:23,886] {cli_action_loggers.py:105} WARNING - Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: log
[SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('2022-02-22 06:46:23.880923', 'dag id', 'task id', 'cli_task_run', None, 'airflow', '{"host_name": "pod name", "full_command": "[\'/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow\', \'tasks\', \ task id\', \'manual__2022-02-22T06:45:47.840912+00:00\', \'--local\', \'--subdir\', \'DAGS_FOLDER/dag_file.py\']"}')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
[2022-02-22 06:46:23,888] {dagbag.py:500} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/repo/xxxxx.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 48, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 282, in task_run
    dag = get_dag(args.subdir, args.dag_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 193, in get_dag
    f"Dag {dag_id!r} could not be found; either it does not exist or it failed to parse."
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Dag 'xxxxx' could not be found; either it does not exist or it failed to parse
```

I did try exec into the webserver and scheduler using "kubectl exec -it airflow-dev-webserver-6c5755d5dd-262wd -n dev --container webserver -- /bin/sh". I could see all the dags under /opt/airflow/dags/repo/. Even in the error it says Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/repo/ but couldn't understand what's making the task execution to go into queued state.

Comment: Just observed that the example DAGs are able to execute successfully. For that I just changed the value of "AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES" as True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue using below steps:

I triggered a DAG after which I could see a task pod going into error state. So I did "kubectl logs {pod_name} git-sync" to check whether the DAGs are being copied in the first place or not. Then I found this below error:
image

Then I realized that it is the problem with permissions for writing the DAGs to the DAGs folder. For this I tried changing the "readOnly: false" under "volumeMounts" section.
image

That's it!!! It worked. Below worked finally:

Pod Template File:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    component: worker
    release: airflow-dev
    tier: airflow
spec:
  containers:
  - args: []
    command: []
    env:
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY
      value: ECR repo link
    - name: AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT
      value: '587'
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG
      value: docker image tag
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_SYNC_RUN_AS_USER
      value: '65533'
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING
      value: 'True'
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__LOGS_VOLUME_CLAIM
      value: dw-airflow-dev-logs
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__RUN_AS_USER
      value: '50000'
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_IN_IMAGE
      value: 'False'
    - name: AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__SCHEDULE_AFTER_TASK_EXECUTION
      value: 'False'
    - name: AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM
      value: email id
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES
      value: 'False'
    - name: AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD
      value: xxxxxxxxx
    - name: AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST
      value: smtp-relay.gmail.com
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__NAMESPACE
      value: dev
    - name: AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER
      value: xxxxxxxxxx
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR
      value: LocalExecutor
    - name: AIRFLOW_HOME
      value: /opt/airflow
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER
      value: /opt/airflow/dags
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_DAGS_FOLDER_MOUNT_POINT
      value: /opt/airflow/dags
    - name: AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__FS_GROUP
      value: "50000"
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: connection
          name: airflow-dev-airflow-metadata
    - name: AIRFLOW_CONN_AIRFLOW_DB
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: connection
          name: airflow-dev-airflow-metadata
    - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: fernet-key
          name: airflow-dev-fernet-key
    envFrom: []
    image: docker image
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: base
    ports: []
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/airflow/dags
      name: airflow-dags
      readOnly: false
      subPath: /repo
    - mountPath: /opt/airflow/logs
      name: airflow-logs
    - mountPath: /etc/git-secret/ssh
      name: git-sync-ssh-key
      subPath: ssh
    - mountPath: /opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
      name: airflow-config
      readOnly: true
      subPath: airflow.cfg
    - mountPath: /opt/airflow/config/airflow_local_settings.py
      name: airflow-config
      readOnly: true
      subPath: airflow_local_settings.py
  hostNetwork: false
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: airflow-dev-registry
  initContainers:
  - env:
    - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
      value: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - name: GIT_SYNC_BRANCH
      value: master
    - name: GIT_SYNC_ROOT
      value: /git
    - name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
      value: repo
    - name: GIT_SYNC_DEPTH
      value: '1'
    - name: GIT_SYNC_ONE_TIME
      value: 'true'
    - name: GIT_SYNC_REV
      value: HEAD
    - name: GIT_SSH_KEY_FILE
      value: /etc/git-secret/ssh
    - name: GIT_SYNC_ADD_USER
      value: 'true'
    - name: GIT_SYNC_SSH
      value: 'true'
    - name: GIT_KNOWN_HOSTS
      value: 'false'
    image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync:v3.1.6
    name: git-sync
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 65533
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /git
      name: airflow-dags
      readOnly: false
    - mountPath: /etc/git-secret/ssh
      name: git-sync-ssh-key
      subPath: ssh
  nodeSelector: {}
  restartPolicy: Never
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 50000
    runAsUser: 50000
  serviceAccountName: airflow-dev-worker-serviceaccount
  volumes:
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: airflow-dags
  - name: airflow-logs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dw-airflow-dev-logs
  - name: git-sync-ssh-key
    secret:
      items:
      - key: gitSshKey
        mode: `444`
        path: ssh
      secretName: airflow-private-dags-dev
  - configMap:
      name: airflow-dev-airflow-config
    name: airflow-config [](url)
```